# FIGMA - How to delete sections/elements of a component?

Tags: figma

In Figma.

As seen in the pic:
[image]

**How do I delete the highlighted Section from the Component?**

When I press Delete or Backspace the element hides, and there is no contextual menu option to delete, or even disconnect.

I have noted that plenty of people complain about it online. Is there an option or an add-on?

**Here is my XY Problem, so maybe you can solve the actual problem.**
I have synchronised AWS with Figma and just want to copy the provided components and paste them and then be able to edit them, and during edit I am unable to remove the pieces I do not like.

The original Component Name also appears in brackets after my new Component name and so this seem a little broken too, it is not a proper copy and paste and then name change.

Surely I do not have to recreate from scratch, otherwise I might as well build it directly on the webserver and not share these designs across the team. seems kinda strange that an simple design tool cannot simply copy paste and then lastly edit (delete)

Comment: Hi. I can't reproduce the problem. When I try creating a component in Figma, with multiple elements, it's possible to go into the component, and select and delete one element either using the backspace or delete key. Perhaps this has something to do with the way the document has been set up?  What is AWS?

Comment: weird because this problem is all over the web, lots of people ask this question but no answer solves the problem.
AWS = Amazon Web Services
Specifically Amplify

Comment: Do you have purple text like me? and is the component connected to a front-end web platform?

Comment: No. I just used simple components using the standard figma tools. The problem may be caused by the service you are using.  I don't really know TBH. Sorry, wish I could help more.

Answer (score 1):

Figma doesn't allow you to delete objects inside component instances, only inside components themselves.

In the object sidebar, component instances are differentiated from components using their icon:

- 4 small diamonds = component
- 1 big diamond = component instance

You seem to have a component instance inside of your component. To make edits, you need to convert the component instance into a simple frame. You can do that by **right-clicking it and selecting "Detach instance"**.

See the [Figma docs](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038665754-Detach-an-Instance-from-the-Component) for more info.